# MVC6 get current url in a view with razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Before we could use the request object to retrieve the current url in a view:

```
@Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

How can I do this in MVC6? (I'm using the dnx451 framework)

Comment: I am not entirely sure it is a duplicate. The linked question was intended for generating new absolute uris, while in this one the user wants to get the absolute uri of the current request, not generate a new one. I have edited the original question to explain how to get the absolute uri of the current request, which feels like it should be its own different answer in this question

Comment: if you agree we could vote to reopen and move the answer to this question instead